# Unable to retrieve value from DB 

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am unable to retrieve the value from DB. Please go through the code and guide me in solving it

```
public ArrayList  getReqResInfo(String id) 
{
    String methodname="createConnection";
    Connection conn  = null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    PreparedStatement psmt;
    int req_id=0;
    String reqid=id;
    ArrayList resList=new ArrayList();
    try {
        conn = DBConnection.getJNDIConnection();
        System.out.println("getReqResInfo id=="+reqid);
        psmt= conn.prepareStatement("select * from CR_REQUEST_RESOURCE_INFO where REQUEST_ID=?");
        psmt.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(id));
        rs= psmt.executeQuery();
        System.out.println("getReqResInfo");

        while(rs.next())
        { 
            System.out.println(rs.getString("RES_LEVEL") +" " + rs.getString("NOOF_RES") +" " + rs.getString("RES_PRIMARY_SKILL") +" " + rs.getString("RES_QUALIFICATION") +" " + rs.getString("RES_SECONDARY_SKILL") +" " + rs.getString("RES_EXP"));              
            ReqResourceVO resourceVO=new ReqResourceVO();
            resourceVO.setLevel(rs.getString("RES_LEVEL"));
            resourceVO.setNumres(rs.getString("NOOF_RES"));
            resourceVO.setPrimary(rs.getString("RES_PRIMARY_SKILL"));
            resourceVO.setQualification(rs.getString("RES_QUALIFICATION"));
            resourceVO.setSecondary(rs.getString("RES_SECONDARY_SKILL"));
            resourceVO.setYear(rs.getString("RES_EXP"));

            resList.add(resourceVO);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    { 
        try {
            conn.close();
        } 
        catch(Exception e)
        { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
    }

    return  resList;
}
```

In the servlet I am calling this function as mentioned below

```
if(action.equals("view"))
{
    try
    { 
        String reqid=req.getParameter("id");
        System.out.println("id "+reqid);
        ReqProjVO reqProjVO=new ReqProjVO();
        reqProjVO.setRequestid(reqid);
        ReqResDAO reqresDAO=new ReqResDAO();
        reqProjVO=reqresDAO.getReqProjInfo(reqProjVO);
        ArrayList resVOList=reqresDAO.getReqResInfo(reqid);
        req.setAttribute("projVO", reqProjVO);
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("resVOList", resVOList);

        ReqProjDAO reqprojDAO=new ReqProjDAO();
        ArrayList projList=reqprojDAO.Project();
        req.setAttribute("projList", projList);
        System.out.println("in request resource servlet");
        RequestDispatcher rd= req.getRequestDispatcher("jsp/manager/RequestforResource.jsp");
        rd.forward(req,res);
        System.out.println("in request resource servlet");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Values are being fetched from the DB and it is printed on the console but it is not forwarding to the concerned JSP page it is going to the log in JSP page and I am getting this huge error. I dont know what to do...

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
    at weblogic.utils.io.ChunkedOutputStream.writeTo(ChunkedOutputStream.java:193)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ResponseHeaders.writeHeaders(ResponseHeaders.java:434)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.writeHeaders (ServletResponseImpl.java:1256)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletOutputStreamImpl.sendHeaders(Servlet OutputStreamImpl.java:244)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.flush(ChunkOutput.java:379)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.checkForFlush(ChunkOutput.java:469)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.write(ChunkOutput.java:304)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutputWrapper.write(ChunkOutputWrapper.java:139)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspWriterImpl.write(JspWriterImpl.java:274)
    at jsp_servlet._jsp._manager.__requestforresource._jspService(__requestforresource.java:237)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run (StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet    StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.onAddToMapException(ServletStubImpl.java:408)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:318)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:505)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:251)
    at manager.RequestResourceServlet.doPost(RequestResourceServlet.java:181)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3498)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2180)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2086)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1406)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you have shown us (`getReqResInfo()`) does not appear in the stack trace.  The only part of the stack trace that appears to be in your own code is `manager.RequestResourceServlet.doPost()`, so it's likely the problem lies there.  If you can find the problem yourself in `RequestResourceServlet.java:181` then great! Otherwise, provide more code.

Extra helpful advice for you:

Your method returns an `ArrayList`.  Better to specify the interface type, `List` instead (best practise: program to interfaces rather than concrete types so they can easily be changed later).  Also, note that `List`s are generic.  You should specify that your list is a list of `ReqResourceVO`, so write `List<ReqResourceVO>`.  Using generics means your collection is type-safe and you don't need extra casting later.

It's good to see that you know how to use `finally` to close the connection at the end, but don't forget to also close the resultset and the statement.  :)

Comment: i have added servlet coding please go through it and help me to solve this. almost from yesterday i am struggling with this....

Comment: If you look closely at the stack trace, the method that you call from within your `doPost()` method is called `forward()` and indeed you make a call to `rd.forward(req,res);` in your code. I'm not an expert on servlets but the problem must be with your dispatcher.

Comment: If it's working for you in other places, clearly the problem lies in whatever differs from the working servlets.  It's pretty much down to trial and error - comment out lines of your code until it does work, and then you will have your answer.  Also, do your other servlets dispatch to the same location (`jsp/manager/RequestforResource.jsp`)?

Answer (score 3):

This exception occurs when a client made a request, and before receiving the full response, either of the following happened:

1. client's browser has been closed.
2. client's connection has been disconnected.
3. client presses the stop button.

[More info](http://www.websina.com/bugzero/errors/http-connection-reset.html).

Answer (score 0):

In req.getRequestDispatcher call my interest points to the path of the jsp page. Should you try starting it with a slash / like many examples I have found are starting? So it starts /jsp/ instead of plain jsp/

Comment: path is working fine for all the modules no problem with that. i guess there is some db prob but i am unable to identify it.